# Equation with function. At least two variables

Tags: functions

I have the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and also 
$f(x^2+x)+f(4x-2)=ln(x^2-3x+3)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I need to prove that the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least 2 values.

I really dont understand why $x^2+x=4x-2$ where will this help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is hard to work with, but will simplify if $f(x^2+x) = f(4x+2)$.  That will be definitely true if if $x^2 + x = 4x+2$, which is $x^2-3x+2 = 0$, which has solutions $x = 1$ and $x=2$.

In those cases, the equation reduces to $f(2) = \ln(1) = 0$ and $f(6) = \ln(1) = 0$.

Comment: to clarify i know x^2+x = 4x-2 cause it said so in the "hint" but whithout knowing it i wouldnt be able to solve it. is there anything that i dont see in the actual question?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  The equation is fairly horribly looking, and the first thing I'd try is to take the special case of $x^2+x = 4x-2$.  I don't know how you'd solve the full functional equation

Answer (score 1):

Let me try. Put $x=1$, one has $f(2) + f(2) = \ln (1) = 0$, then $f(2) = 0$.

Put $x = 2$, one has $f(6) + f(6) = \ln(1) = 0$, then $f(6) = 0$.

So, we get the conclusion.